Intuition behind conversion factors increasing/decreasing for longer dated expiries?
I'm trying to intuitively reason why the below claim from The Treasury Bond Basis is true.

Conversion factors are unique to each bond and to each delivery month.
Note in Exhibit 1.3 that conversion factors for bonds with coupons
higher than 6% become smaller for each successive contract month to
reflect the drift toward par of its price as it approaches maturity.
Similarly, the conversion factors of bonds with coupons less than 6%
drift upward for successive contract months.

It feels to me like this would be a function of the prevailing yields, not a fixed 6%. Take a 5% coupon bond for example in a 4% rate environment—in this case, conversion factor < 1 but the bond will be trading at a premium and will decay towards par, so I would think the CF would also decrease as well to account for this and keep futures price constant as time to expiry increases. But it seems I'm missing something as the switch from increasing to decreasing happens at the CF = 1 boundary as stated in the text. Is it just making the assumption that if the CF < 1 i.e. the yield is < 6% on the bond then it will be trading at a discount and increasing in price towards par? That feels like a strange assumption though given the rates have historically been so low. 

The cf is 0.01x the price of the bond if it yielded 6%, on the first delivery (i think). That's a definition, not something up for debate (I.e. it's contractual). For bonds with coupons lower than 6%, their CF<1, which is obvious. As the term to expiry increases, the bond at delivery will have a shorter expiry, therefore will pull to par implying a higher cf.

Although some bond futures don't use exactly 6%, and some have slightly different calculation rules (e.g. CBOT US treasuries or EUREX bond futures) @user68819 's comment captures exactly the right essence. All calculations very closely capture the scaled price of the bond for a contract specification coupon (e.g. 6%) at a delivery date. So his/her claim that it is a definition and how other factors affect the price are entirely relevant. The additional factor is shorter bonds have smaller durations so a deviation in their current yield from the contract spec yield will give smaller...

deviations from the standard 1.0 conversion factor.

I think that’s what I’m not understanding—I completely understand the definitional aspect of the CF standardizing to 6% yield, but why intuitively is the smaller duration the determining factor in how far the CF is away from 1?

Becuase if mkt rates are 5% and the futures spec coupon is 6%, then a 5y bond with 5% coupon that has a duration of, say 4.5, is likely to be priced somewhere like 95.5 for a 6% YTM. On the other hand, a 10y bond with a 5% coupon with a duration of say, 9, is likely to be priced somewhere like 91.0 for a 6% YTM. You can do the exploration yourself, just plug in numbers into a pricer. Theres nothing more to it than this.
